# Questions about punctuation and capitalizaton of letters (mail), forms, sections, exhibits, etc

Tags: capitalization, quotation-marks

According to the Chicago Manual of Style, you shouldn't capitalize chapters, so would this include exhibits, sections, boxes (box A), and parts (part I), too? Also, would you put the names of forms, letters (as in letters you mail), exhibits, sections, checklists, etc., in quotation marks? It's very hard to find answers to these questions. =/ Concrete examples (besides ones above): Exhibit B-12, Payroll Authorization Form, Labor Relations letter, section B, Wage Decision Checklist, Verification of Wages section.

Comment: Absent concrete examples it's hard to discern what exactly you're asking here.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site encourages the posting of definitive answers. It's difficult to be definitive about matters of style, and harder yet to be definitive *in the general case* about such matters. Can you please post the extract from CMoS together with some examples?

Comment: Check your local style guide. If none, do whatever you want. Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: _Chicago_ recommends "part 1," "chapter 4," figure 7," "exhibit 12," etc.—but this is simply a default preference. Every publishing house has its own guidelines on how to style these elements, and many choose to initial-cap the element name (_Chapter_, _Part_, _Figure_, _Exhibit_, etc. There is no right or wrong rule beyond what the controlling style preference happens to be. As for your other questions (which are also style preferences), I wouldn't initial-cap any of the examples you list unless it was the proper name of the thing mentioned, nor would I put any of those words in quotes. ...

Comment: ... The one exception would be _Verification of Wages section_, if that phrase refers to a section of a document that appears under the subhead "Verification of Wages." In that case I would both initial-cap the subhead name and put it in quotation marks. As for entities such as _Payroll Authorization Form_, if you're dealing with a generic payroll authorization form, I would lowercase the words because they don't constitute a proper name. But if the form had an official name such as _Payroll Authorization Form (Form GX116A)_, I would initial-cap it but omit quotes: Payroll Authorization Form.

Answer (score 1):

The safest answer, outside of opinion, is to go with the basic scheme of capitalizing proper nouns but lower case for common nouns.  *Chicago* encourages thoughtful solutions to unique circumstances with the premise of reader comprehension. Some of your examples:

**exhibit B-12** there are lots of exhibits

**Genetics exhibit** lots of exhibits, one exhibit for genetics

**Payroll Authorization form** there are lots of forms, but only one for payroll authorization

**Verification of Wages section**

**Wage Decision Checklist** could go either way

**Labor Relations letter** but *a letter about labor relations*

Comment: As for whether or not to capitalize names of forms and letters, I figured they would be capitalized. I was mainly asking about capitalization for exhibits, etc. What I really need to know is if I should put names of forms, letters, etc., in quotation marks.

Comment: Only used as *Chicago* supports for quotation marks: episode names within a larger series, songs, etc. Otherwise, no.

Comment: No italics either? I would just write Labor Relations letter and Payroll Authorization form exactly like that? I would think "Verification of Wages" section would have quotation marks since it is part of a larger work.

Comment: Correct. The capitalization generally signifies to the reader you are meaning something specific. Again, there are specific examples within *Chicago*. Beyond that, you're talking typesetting which is an editor's choice type of thing.